# Some thinking about the Dini' s Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

In the Dini's Theorem, On the compact set $K$,if $f_n$ is a sequence of monotone increasing or decreasing continuous functions, i,e $f_n(x)\leq(\geq) f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x$, converges pointwisely to a continuous function $f$, then the convergence is uniform.

But now if we only know that each continuous function $f_n$ is monotone w.r.t x, but do not know for each $x$, whether $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$, or $f_n(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x)$, then can we prove the convergence is uniform? Or can we find a countereample?

Comment: At the very least, it is difficult to find a counterexample.  By Arzela-Ascoli, if each $f_n$ is continuous, we have to produce a sequence $\{f_n\}$ that fails to be equicontinuous.

Comment: In the statement of Dini's theorem, each $f_n$ is continuous

Comment: Can't you just replace $g_n = f - f_n$ by $g_n = |f - f_n|$ in the proof http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Comment: @user66081 why should $g_n$ satisfy $g_{n+1}(x) \leq g_n(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Regarding your recent ephemeral question, I guess you found the proof of equicontinuity yourself?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think *This is much healthier's* proof works perfectly well

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose I could put the question back up though, if you had another approach

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It does. But I thought you might be interested in the answer to your question nevertheless. The family is equicontinuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've decided to undelete it after all.  It should be up now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informal "proof". Suppose $f$ and $f_n$ are increasing. Draw their graphs and turn the  paper $45$ degrees clockwise. Now you see a sequence of $1$-Lipschitz (hence equicontinuous) functions converging pointwise. The Arzelà–Ascoli theorem implies that the convergence is uniform.

---

Now let's be serious. Using the continuity of $f$, partition its domain into subintervals on each of which  the oscillation of $f$ is less than $\epsilon$. For large $n$, the difference $|f_n-f|$ is less than $\epsilon$ at every partition point. By monotonicity, $|f_n-f|\le 2\epsilon$ everywhere.

Explanation of the latter: say, the values of $f$ on some subinterval are between $a$ and $a+\epsilon$. Since $|f_n-f|\le \epsilon$ at the endpoints, and $f_n$ is monotone, we have $a- \epsilon \le f_n \le a+2\epsilon$ on the subinterval. Conclusion follows.

Comment: Why should it be the case that $f_{n}(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x)$ holds for each $n$ and each $x \in K_1$?

Comment: nice and short proof...

Comment: $f_n$ and $f$ are increasing w.r.t $x$, not $n$, how did you get $f_n-f$ is monotone?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, did you work it out? while omitting the condition''monotone w.r.t n'' from Dini's Lemma, what is your opinion? Can we prove uniform convergence or can't?

Comment: @user157361 The difference is not monotone. But we can use monotonicity of functions to bound it. I'll expand on this point a bit.

Comment: @This is much healthier. Oh, I understand now.