# Sequence of continuous function converging pointwise to continuous function is equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

I've proven the following "theorem":

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, $(f_n: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of continuous functions converging pointwise to a continuous function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on $I$. Then: $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equicontinuous on I.

Now my problem is, that here [Equicontinuity of a pointwise convergent sequence of monotone functions with continuous limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854632/equicontinuity-of-a-pointwise-convergent-sequence-of-monotone-functions-with-con) additionally  the $f_n$ have to be monotonic. So is my proof a generalization, or am I just missing something? Here is my proof:

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Observe first:
\begin{equation}
| f_n(x) - f_n(y) | \leq |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)| + |f(x)- f(y)|
\end{equation}
Now there is by pointwise convergence of $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $|f_n(y) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Further there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for $|x-y| < \delta$ by continuity of $f$. Hence we have shown, that there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $n \geq N$ 
\begin{equation}
|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon
\end{equation}
holds. Now let $n < N$. Then, by continuity of $f_n$ there is a $\delta_n$ such that $(x-y) < \delta_n$ implies $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon$. Setting
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\delta} = \min_{n < N} \delta_n
\end{equation}
(which exists and is greater than $0$) we obtain, that for all $n < N$ the following holds:
\begin{equation}
|x - y| < \tilde{\delta} \Rightarrow |f_n(x) - f_n(y) | < \epsilon
\end{equation}
Setting now $\hat{\delta} = \min \{\delta, \tilde{\delta} \}$ we have, that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds:
\begin{equation}
|x-y| < \hat{\delta} \Rightarrow |f_n(x)- f_n(y) | < \epsilon
\end{equation}
Hence we have shown, that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\hat{\delta} > 0$ such that forall $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have, that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Can your interval be  open?

Comment: Yes, i stated no assumptions regarding the interval.

Comment: The functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ converge to 0 pointwise on $(0,1)$ but not uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is wrong, because it basically impmies that every pointwise convergence of continuous functions to a continuous function is uniform. I think the flaw is that your $N$ depends both on $x$ (not important, it is fixed) but in $y$ as well!